# Does PHP take care of the character encoding of variables in $_GET and $_POST? (PHP 5.4)

Tags: php, character-encoding, http-post, query-string, http-get

My script is written in UTF-8 and the MySQL database tables it uses have the collation utf8_unicode_ci. Now if I want to compare strings from `$_GET`/`$_POST` with 'internal' strings from the script/database or even put something into the database, do I have to check/fix the encoding of the variables or did PHP already do that for me?

If the former is the case, can I simply do the following at the beginning of my script?

```
function inputToUtf8($string) {
  $detectedEncoding = mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-8,ISO-8859-1', true);
  if ($detectedEncoding == 'UTF-8') {
    return $string;
  } elseif ($detectedEncoding == 'ISO-8859-1') {
    return utf8_encode($string);
  }
  throw new Exception('Invalid character encoding detected.');
}

foreach ($_GET as &$v) $v = inputToUtf8($v); unset($v);
foreach ($_POST as &$v) $v = inputToUtf8($v); unset($v);
```

Comment: I wonder if this function will ever throw an exception. The return value of mb_detect_string is explained as 'the detected character encoding or FALSE if the encoding cannot be detected from the given string'. But it seems to always return 'ISO-8859-1' if the string is not valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't do that for you, but client browser often does. It is normal to send the GET/POST data in the encoding that your HTML page is in, so if you have specified the character encoding correctly for the HTML page, the browsers should and generally also will use the same.

Of course, it is better to make sure than just assume - at least if you need to be sure about it.

Edit: To make this clear - by making sure I meant filtering out characters that do not match the character set you're expecting. You should set, expect and support only one character set at a time.

Comment: There is no way to make sure, because detecting encoding is just guessing. It will not help you, just create another potential problem when wrong encoding is detected.

Comment: @user1660584 I wasn't talking about detecting - I was talking about filtering out unknown characters if you need to be sure that only proper ones are being worked on. Guess I could've made that more clear.

Comment: well, in that case, you should NOT use utf8_encode neither detecting encoding. You are probably looking for a regular expression removing all unwanted characters (it is also not clean what is an unknown character - yes, in UTF8 you may have completely invalid sequence, but usually every charcode is some character with some meaning).

Comment: @user1660584 I would not recommend regular expressions, there is `iconv('utf-8', 'utf-8//ignore', $str);` for example. [Iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) is the preferred way to deal with encoding conversions.

Comment: it depends if OP wants to remove only really malicious characters, or all "weird" characters and leave i.e. only alphanumerics, spaces and common special characters (@#$...)

Comment: well, if that were the case there'd be no sense with doing anything with character sets.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to detect the encoding, because:

- All correctly working web browsers are sending the data in the same encoding as your page is. No exceptions.
- Detecting encoding is not 100% precise. A string can be (and usually is) valid in multiple encodings, so wrong encoding may be detected and conversion will make a mess.

Comment: To say there are no exceptions is just wrong. There are exceptions, such as 1) http header content type, which might or might not be present, as a user can have saved the page locally, 2) form accept-encoding charset parameter can contradict the page charset, 3) page can be of different encoding that it is specified at, 4) user can have just changed into different encoding from browser options. But *generally* the data is sent using the same encoding.

Comment: 1) well, it is not a good practice to not specify encoding in HTML header. well, it may lead you into problems. 2) yes, but you are still aware of what encoding your PHP will receive. 3) then the page is also wrongly displayed which is usually bigger problem. 4) yes, he can also send HTTP request from telnet.
My point is that if your page is written correctly and user is not trying to hack it, you always know what encoding you will receive, really without exceptions. But thanks for extra information, you are true, but I'm afraid that it's not this case.

Comment: on the 4th, I've seen cases where a user does that by accident, it doesn't have to be malicious. Or due to some ill advise or misunderstanding. I think that happens way more often than sending HTTP requests using telnet. But ok, it's beside the point already. :)